# Is WWE (Wrestling) Fake or Real?

Tags: sport

Is American Wrestling staged? Do the wrestlers really beat each other to blood and break bones? Have they already decided the winner and all is the mess created during a match just a staged performance?

Comment: This needs a notable claim

Comment: @DVK I've definitely heard this one several times from several sources, and I think it's notable. Just needs some links to notable claims added.

Comment: I always though this is a common knowledge, a question like: "Are action movies staged? Do the actors really beat other to blood ..."?

Comment: When Steve Austin confronted Mike Tyson in 2007. The chairman of WWF said that was out of script and was not part of rehearsal. That means it is all scripted.

Comment: @Suma No one calls wrestlers the 'actors', while even a child know that characters in movies etc are just doing acting.

Comment: @LifeH2O: No, they do not call them actors, they call them "Superstars and Divas". Now seriously: the producer is not reminding the public what they are seeing is a show only, but it is not a secret and anyone wishing to know can learn this. "By and large, the true nature of the performance is not discussed by the performing company in order to sustain and promote the willing suspension of disbelief " http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_wrestling

Comment: I've never heard anyone doubting if it's scripted. It is a common knowledge indeed.

Comment: @Sejanus May be it is a common knowledge in your country, but not in mine.

Comment: In my opinion WWE treads a fine line between truth and lie here.

Comment: I call wrestlers actors.

Comment: @DVK The wrestler with stage name "Mr Anderson" sometimes wears a shirt that says **"Wrestling is real.  People are fake."**  I decided not to include a link to a T-shirt shop, but the phrase is googlable.

Comment: It's 80% is fake. Whenever they forgots their line they go near by other in ear n tells the line.

Comment: Both.  Yes, WWE wrestling is staged, but Yes people actually do get hurt injured while doing it.

Comment: This is really a question?

Comment: "fake" is a loaded word. it is predetermined and choreographed, sometimes scripted, sometimes improvised. The WWE in particular has admitted this in US Federal Court in order to avoid the *far stricter* regulations on sports than entertainment.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's clearly a representation of a script and not a real fight at all.

This is what a WWE event is, [according to WWE](http://corporate.wwe.com/company/events.jsp):

> Live events and television programming are our principal creative content and production activities. **Our creative team develops compelling and complex characters and weaves them into dynamic storylines that combine physical and emotional elements. Storylines are usually played out in the ring** and unfold on our weekly television shows, and culminate in our monthly pay-per-view events.

In other words, a creative team scripts a storyline (including how the fight develops) which is then *played out* on the ring by "Superstars" and "Divas".

Comment: Although it's a script being played out cooperatively, I think it's well-established that a surprising amount of the gore is real.

Comment: real pig gore? :)

Comment: Can we now tag this question with "Gross" tag?

Comment: @jwenting Wrestlers will poke themselves in the hairline with a thin sliver of a razor blade to induce bleeding. The documentary "Beyond the Mat" covers fairly extensively what's "real" and not. The storylines and outcomes of the fight are generally pre-arranged, and the wrestlers will often choreograph their fight beforehand, but the chair shots/ladders/thumb tacks/blood are all definitely real. Wrestlers are damn good athletes, whatever one thinks of the productions they take part in.

Comment: @jozzas: good athletes, yes. good actors, absolutely not.

Comment: It's still real to me! Dammit!

Comment: @JohnLyon: "Blading" or "gigging" to get "color" is forbidden in many promotions and for that matter by the sports commissions (wrestling often falling under the same umbrella as other combat sports), so fake blood capsules or condoms filled with blood are also used to simulate bleeding.  And, of course, injuries still happen, and some wrestlers will still try to pretend they didn't cut themselves. Source, a friend of mine who runs a local promotion, who has to deal with the fines when they do so.